# How to save array on file fast?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, multidimensional-array, nodes

I made the array `var QL = [[],[],[],[]];` with size `[100][20][100][3]` and I need to save the array every time that my program finish and when my program start again **IF** the file exist, then just load.
**Question**

1- How do this fast (my code is below, but is very slow !) ?

2 -How to load fast ?

```
QLearn.QLSave = function (){
var jsonQtable = [];
for (var a=0; a<100; a++) {
    for (var b=0; b<20; b++) {
        for (var c=0; c<100; c++){
            for (var d=0; d<2; d++){
                jsonQtable.push(QL[a,b,c,d].toJSON)
            }
        }
    }
}
QLearn.ui.logger.log('Saving QL...');
var dir = './Qtable';
var fileName = dir + '/QL'+'.json';
fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(jsonQtable), function (err){
    if (err) {
        QLearn.ui.logger.log('Failed to save! '+err);
    } else {
        QLearn.ui.logger.log('Saved to '+fileName);
    }
});}
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify(QL)`, then `JSON.parse(fileContents)`...?

Answer (score 0):

Intead you write the file in batch, an solution is append file in each iteration, using [fs.appendFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_file_data_options_callback):

```
QLearn.QLSave = function (){
var jsonQtable = [];
for (var a=0; a<100; a++) {
    for (var b=0; b<20; b++) {
        for (var c=0; c<100; c++){
            for (var d=0; d<2; d++){
                fs.appendFile(fileName, QL[a,b,c,d].toJSON, function (err) {
                   if (!err){ 
                      console.log("Success in insert: " + QL[a,b,c,d].toJSON);
                   }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That would cost to open a file descriptor for each iteration, meaning that sounds worst.

Comment: @a0viedo, I agree with you, but I proposed an solution for to append in execution time of loop, not in batch. Searching now, I saw this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/append-stream, as suggest is faster than both and do not open file in each iteration :)